# WSO2 Identity Server JWT Access token

Tags: wso2, jwt, access-token, oauth-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to receive a JWT access_token from WSO2 Identity Server when logging in with password grant_type.
But I can't find any way to configure this. When I sign in I get a guid as access_token.

I found this, but this is the way to get the access_token guid when you have a JWT: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+JWT+Grant+Type

Also I enable JWT Token generation using this tutorial, but I'm still receiving the guid: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/JWT+Token+Generation

When I set true in identity.xml I get a base64 hashed access_token, but this is not in JWT format.

Has anyone figured this out?

Comment: trying sending scope=openid along with the password grant type request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenID connect to get a JWT. [1] shows how to configure OIDC in Identity Server. I think you already have done that. So try sending scope=openid along with the token request.

Also, check [2] for a known bug and workaround related to OIDC in Identity Server 5.2.0

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=50514076

[2] [WSO2 IS: OpenID Connect custom claims in 5.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959064/wso2-is-openid-connect-custom-claims-in-5-2-0/40042390#40042390)

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. What you are referring to is the id_token, which already is a JWT. What the John is referring to is the access_token, which right now is a UUID. I have the same question as well.

Comment: so what you want is something like an access_token which is self descriptive right? So that you can use the meta data without introspecting it every time from an endpoint.

Comment: Yes, that is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to follow [this blog](http://wdfdo1986.blogspot.jp/2016/11/generate-jwt-access-tokens-from-wso2.html)  to generate JWT access token with WSO2 IS

also, you might want to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086489/wso2-is-change-the-embedded-database-schema) to push the database schema changes into effect