# Securing WSO2 microservices with JWT using WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, jwt, microservices, msf4j, wso2-identity-server

I found this:

[WSO2 Identity Server JWT Access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255523/wso2-identity-server-jwt-access-token)

but it doesn't seem to be answered.

What I want to do is this:

1 - call some URL on the WSO2 Identity Server to authenticate, sending a username and password, and have it send me back a Json Web Token (JWT). It's possible this will have to be 2 calls, one to authenticate and one to retrieve the JWT but I'd really really like to avoid that.

2 - pass the JWT along to WSO2 microservices via the Authorization: Bearer header

3 - have the microservices automatically validate the JWT and get the user information so I can build a security context. I expect this will need to call back to the WSO2 Identity Server for every call.

Is there a step by step guide to getting this working? Everything I see involves redirecting the user to log in at the WSO2 identity server or generating a JWT which is app client specific, not user specific. This should be front and center for the MSF4J documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the MSF4J JWT claim sample. It explains scenario step by step the https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/v2.1.0/samples/jwt-claims

Comment: It really doesn't: `1) Open the travelocity web app from http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com

2) Login using your credentials with SAML SSO.

3) Click on Request OAuth2 Access Token and send to micro service.`

Comment: I want to log in via an HTTP POST, not via a webpage