# WSO2 Identity Server not returning roles claims with OAuth/OpenID

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using IS 5.2.0 and having an issue getting back roles in the openid claim. I mapped a role claim in http://wso2.org/oidc/claim to the http://wso2.org/claims dialect. I have successfully mapped other claims like username and fullname and get those back but not able to get back roles. Is there something I'm missing, is it possible?

Appreciate any help,

Comment: please share your works and errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 IS: OpenID Connect custom claims in 5.2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959064/wso2-is-openid-connect-custom-claims-in-5-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new claim(other than default claim) in OIDC registry scope entry in Identity Server. You can found more details here [1].

[1] https://workaroundz.blogspot.com/2016/10/define-custom-claims-for-openid-connect.html

Comment: Thank you for the help, I was able to get it working.