# Unable to get custom claims in JWT token

Tags: wso2, jwt, openid, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 5.4.1 IDP and its configured to handle my custom claims.
When i request token with the scope=openid it only returns the **sub** claim.
I want to get user roles as well but i am unable to get those in my id_token.

Following steps i have already done

1. In _system/conf/identity/oidc and adding claim
2. Use Local Claim Dialect and Define Custom Claim Dialect for
3. claim configuration in Service Providers.

i want to receive the custom claims in my jwt token. Can anyone help me in this regards?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them as `requested claims`.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS541/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have already tried that as well.
You can see the attachment i added.

Comment: Please check this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959064/wso2-is-openid-connect-custom-claims-in-5-2-0/40042390#40042390